# How to load same plugins from 2 different assemblies, and serializing and deserializing types between the two? C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, serialization

So I have two .net assemblies, one wpf the other a windows service. They talk using wcf with protobuf.net for serializing types.

Everything is working smooth however I just made a primitive plugin system that loads plugins, both assemblies in my project load THE SAME plugins with the intention of sending classes within them over the wire.

So...
1. WPF App loads, loads plugins (.net dlls) with Assembly.LoadFrom
2. WCF App loads plugins (same .net dlls) with Assembly.LoadFrom
3. Both assemblies share a dll (object library) that is explicitly referenced in source code.

All types in Object Library can serialize on one end, go over the wire and deserialize no problem.

Types in the plugins can be serialized on either end, but the other end throws a type not resolved exception when attempting to deserialize, even though they are the same type.

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Do you have any sample code you can share with us that illustrates what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Found out my problem, thanks shotgun for the willingness to help, it would have been a lot of code to show.

Basically protobuf couldn't load the type because it didn't exist in the load context of the application domain. Read some stuff on MSDN had to handle the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event and return the correct assembly for the plugin types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load plugin assemblies, then MEF is a simply excellent solution.